# QQ plot doesn't look great - maybe quasipoisson with random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, overdispersion

I have several `glmer()`-models that look like this:

```
modelZeit <- glmer(Spielzeit ~ INS + Alter + 
                          Geschlecht + (1 | Aufmerksam), 
                   family = poisson(), data = Umfrage)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: Spielzeit ~ INS + Alter + Geschlecht + (1 | Aufmerksam)
   Data: Umfrage

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1253.6   1273.6   -621.8   1243.6      396 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.14324 -0.54997 -0.09786  0.30469  2.89782 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Aufmerksam (Intercept) 0.03224  0.1796  
Number of obs: 401, groups:  Aufmerksam, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.25955    0.17515   7.191 6.43e-13 ***
INS         -0.08183    0.02805  -2.918  0.00353 ** 
Alter       -0.02816    0.03950  -0.713  0.47579    
Geschlechtw -0.15461    0.07461  -2.072  0.03824 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) INS    Alter 
INS         -0.639              
Alter       -0.486 -0.133       
Geschlechtw -0.010 -0.131 -0.040
```

[image: QQ plot, but in the beginnings it's over and later under the red line]
The QQ plot isn't that bad, but also not really nice. I am not really sure, if it is over- or underdispersed. Some test i found said:

```
> dispersion_glmer(modelZeit)
[1] 0.6801336
```

The value is under the recommended range, does this mean it is overdispersed?
I would like to try different families, maybe quasipoisson or negative binomial to see if it fits better, but I dont know how to make a glmer() with these families and I dont want to give up my random effect. When I tried to use glmer.nb() a bunch of errors accoured. (Something with "in theta.ml ... iteration limit reached" and "in checkConc....Model failed to converge...") Also, adding an observation-level random effect didn't improve anything.

Could anybody give me advice on what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a try in the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=GLMMadaptive) package that can fit negative binomial mixed models using also the adaptive Gaussian quadrature approximation that is better than the Laplace approximation offered by **lme4**.

Check the vignettes available under Articles in the website of [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) (e.g., [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html)).

Comment: I just installed and tried it, but it gives me an error:
`Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family,  : 
  A value greater than 22000 has been detected for the shape/size
 parameter of the negative binomial distribution. This typically
 indicates that the Poisson model would be better. Otherwise,
 adjust the 'max_phis_value' control argument.`

Comment: The error message suggests that you do not have over-dispersion.